# How to use let with typedef signals?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to use **let**-constructs instead of **`define** in my TB to access some signals via hierarchical paths. It's not going that great. "Normal" signals seems to work and I can access them, but typedef-signals act strange.

Here's a super simple example code that I use to trigger the error:

```
module dut();

  // Create a type
  typedef struct {
    int foo;
    int bar;
  } ty_fooBar;

  // Instantiate the type
  ty_fooBar fooBar;

  // Create an "alias" for fooBar
  let fooBar2 = fooBar;

  // Assign some values and try to access the struct members
  initial begin
    fooBar.foo = 3;
    fooBar.bar = 7;
    $display("fooBar: %p",  fooBar  );
    $display("fooBar2: %p", fooBar2 );

    $display("fooBar.fooBar: %p",  fooBar.foo  );
    // $display("fooBar2.fooBar: %p", fooBar2.foo );    <- ERROR

  end

endmodule
```

Simulation gives this result:

```
# fooBar: '{foo:3, bar:7}
# fooBar2: '{foo:3, bar:7}
# fooBar.fooBar: 3
```

So, **fooBar** should now be the same as **fooBar2**, ModelSim shows this with the $display command, but for some reason I can access **fooBar.foo** but not **fooBar2.foo**. I tried reading the IEEE standard but that didn't enlighten me.

What's the deal with **let** and **typedef**? Do I have some profound misunderstanding?

Comment: A `let` declaration is not an alias. It is more like a function. If you had `function my_struct my_func; return some_struct; endfunction` you wouldn't expect to be able to write `my_func.some_field`.

Answer (score 2):

The `let` statement combines the flexibility of a  `` `define `` macro with the well formed structure of function.

Like a macro. the `let` arguments get replaced into the body of its definition. they may be typeless.

Like a `function`, a `let` declaration is local to a scope, including a package that can be imported. References to identifiers that are not arguments are searched from the point of the declaration. And finally the problem that you are facing is that a `let` statement can only be called where an expression is allowed. In fact it places parenthesis around the body before substituting.

So your reference to `fooBar2.foo` gets expanded as `(fooBar).foo` which is not legal.

Comment: Thank you Dave - again. What threw me off was that ModelSIm/Questa showed the signals/variables like they would be 100% identical. But that parenthesis business is something I completely missed, and IEEE standard was bit too cryptic for me to comprehend.